# entering "kubectl config use-context" to two different clusters at the same time causes issues in jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, devops, kubectl

In jenkins jobs A and B both the jobs are executed on the same machine to two different clusters. When the "kubectl config use-context" command is entered in both the jobs. They error out with following error. How can this be handled.

looks like use-context changes the file and doing it at the same time from two jobs causes issues.

On job A:

- kubectl config use-context arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:XYZXYZXYZ:cluster/ABC
  error: error loading config file "/home/ubuntu/.kube/config": yaml: line 29: could not find expected ':'

On job B:

- kubectl config use-context arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:XYZXYZXYZ:cluster/CBD
  error: error loading config file "/home/ubuntu/.kube/config": yaml: line 29: could not find expected ':'

Comment: Post the contents in the config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to issue a "use-context" (which yes, does write to the `$KUBECONFIG`) -- kubectl has the `--context` argument that allows you to specify the context to use per invocation:

```
# job A
$ kubectl --context "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:XYZXYZXYZ:cluster/ABC" get nodes
# job B
$ kubectl --context "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:XYZXYZXYZ:cluster/CBD" get nodes
```

However, if you have *a lot* of those commands, that can get tedious. In that case, you may be happier merely copying the original `$KUBECONFIG` and then setting the `KUBECONFIG` env-var in the job to point to your local, effectively disposable, one:

```sh
cp ${KUBECONFIG:-$HOME/.kube/config} job-X.kubeconfig
export KUBECONFIG=$PWD/job-X.kubeconfig
# some copies of kubectl whine if the permissions are too broad
chmod 0600 $KUBECONFIG
# now your use-context is safe to perform
kubectl config use-context "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:XYZXYZXYZ:cluster/ABC"
kubectl get nodes
```

Comment: I did think about mentioning that you're not going to get anywhere until you fix your (now mangled) kubeconfig, but I thought that would be obvious. Obviously not. You're going to have to fix your kubeconfig first, and _then_ prevent it from breaking in the future via concurrent writes. Arguably setting it `chmod a-w` would be a great thing, to keep _other_ jobs from mangling it until they're updated

Comment: wonderful. that seems to work. thank you so much. But I had a question. If I am running multiple simultaneous jobs , dont you think `export KUBECONFIG=$PWD/job-X.kubeconfig` in respective jobs will switch kubeconfig back and forth(to jobs kubeconfig file) causing conflict between jobs ?. 

So far, haven't seen any issue. But was curious.

Comment: Well, `$PWD` for each job should be a distinct folder automatically by Jenkins, but if that's not the case, you can be even _more_ resilient via `KUBECONFIG=$PWD/$(uuidgen).yaml` because `kubectl` doesn't care one iota what the file is named, only that it is yaml, can be read, and contains the information required to authenticate to the specified servers

Comment: great. Thanks a lot!!